# Drawing a simple image, displaying it, and closing it

Tags: python, image, opencv

I am trying to do some simple drawings. I wanted to use opencv (cv2) because on a second project I have to display a small animation (rectangle, size depending on a variable; updated every X seconds). However, I do not have experience with image processing libraries and opencv.

I am running into a lot of problems, one of which is that I do not know how to display/close images. The image I am creating is a simple fixation cross, black; on a light gray background:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

screen_width = 1024
screen_height = 768
img = np.zeros((screen_height, screen_width, 3), np.uint8) # Black image
img = img + 210 # light gray

screen_center = (screen_width//2, screen_height//2)
rect_width = int(0.2*screen_width)
rect_height = int(0.02*screen_height)

xP1 = screen_center[0] - rect_width//2
yP1 = screen_center[1] + rect_height//2
xP2 = screen_center[0] + rect_width//2
yP2 = screen_center[1] - rect_height//2
cv2.rectangle(img, (xP1, yP1), (xP2, yP2), (0, 0, 0), -1)

xP1 = screen_center[0] - rect_height//2
yP1 = screen_center[1] + rect_width//2
xP2 = screen_center[0] + rect_height//2
yP2 = screen_center[1] - rect_width//2
cv2.rectangle(img, (xP1, yP1), (xP2, yP2), (0, 0, 0), -1)
```

N.B: If there is a better way to create it, I am also interested :)

My goal is for this first project to do have the following code structure:

```
img = load_saved_img() # The created fixation cross
display_image()

add_text_to_image('texte to add')
# do stuff
# for several minutes
while something:
    do_this()

remove_text_from_image() # Alternatively, go back to the initial image/change the image
# do stuff
# for several minutes
while something:
    do_this()

close_image()
```

I know I can add text with `cv2.putText()` and that I can this way create a second image with the text. What I do not know is how can I manage the displaying of the different images; especially in a light-weight fashion while "doing stuff" on the background. Most people seems to use `cv2.waitKey()` which is not suited since I do not want to have any user input and since it seems to be something similar to a `time.sleep()` during which the program is basically paused.

Any tips welcome, even on other libraries and implementation :)

Comment: imshow(...) + waitKey(1)

Comment: @Miki Isn't the parameter in waitKey a sleep timer in ms? In your example it would display the image during 1 ms while being in sleep mode and doing nothing?

Comment: yes, but it's needed to refresh OS paint events. There's no other way around

Comment: @Miki After trying it a bit.. does this mean that once cv2.imshow('Visual', Visual.img) and cv2.waitKey(1) are called; a 1 ms will have elapse during which nothing happen; but after that I can do whatever I want until I close the window 'Visual'? Can I also just replace the content of 'Visual' or do I have to close it and open a new one with a new image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As proposed by @Miki, the combination of `.imshow()` and `.waitKey(1)` is working.

```
cv2.imshow(window, img)
cv2.waitKey(1)
```

However, those can not be used with `time.sleep()` to pause the program. Sometimes, the display will not be updated. For instance, on a 3 second countdown:

```
import time
import cv2

window = 'Name of the window'

def countdown(window, images):
    """
    images = [image3, image2, image1]
    """
    for img in images:
        cv2.imshow(window, img)
        cv2.waitKey(1)
        time.sleep(1)
```

Sometimes one of the displays will be skipped. Instead, changing the parameter of `cv2.waitKey()` to `1000` (timer needed) and removing the use of the `time` module works best, if no keyboard input is expected during this time.